# Eclipse @NonNullByDefault error with lombok class using @Value

Tags: java, eclipse, lombok, spring-tool-suite

I am using Spring Tool Suite 4.18.0 (based on Eclipse) with Lombok v1.18.26 with this configuration in lombok.config:

```
config.stopBubbling = true 
lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true
lombok.noArgsConstructor.extraPrivate = false
lombok.addNullAnnotations = eclipse
```

In my package-info.java I have:

```
@org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNullByDefault
package bb.b;
```

In the package bb.b I have the following class:

```
package bb.b;

import lombok.Value;

@Value
public class Test {

}
```

And I am getting the following error:

> Illegal redefinition of parameter o, inherited method from Object does
> not constrain this parameter

How can I configure Eclipse Null checking to play nicely with Lombok?

Comment: See https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/2318

Comment: Seems to be relevant to https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/2867

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is a good solution to your problem...

> HEADSUP: We've changed how this is going to work. We're not going to
> hunt for @NonNullByDefault annotations; these are more usually found
> on the package and that'd take rather a lot of time and complication
> to find, so now whether lombok generates the annotation or not is too
> 'voodoo magical' (it is hard to explain that we see it on classes but
> not on packages!). Also, more generally, sometimes we need to generate
> the 'other' annotation (non-null), in which case there's nothing we
> can see anywhere to tip us off that we need to do that.Therefore,
> instead, there is a lombok.config key where you  configure what kind
> of 'flavour' of nullity annotations you want, and then lombok will
> generate them everywhere that it is relevant (toString, equals,
> canEqual, withX, and plural forms of @Singular properties for a
> builder). This also covers nullity annotations relevant for issue
> 2221.

@cf : https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/788#issuecomment-579276102

Lombok's developer seems to have thrown in the towel... He thinks this is a bad idea to generate non null checks on package level...

@cf: https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/788#issuecomment-318316538

Even I'm globally agree that he seems a bad idea to systematically do a non null check, I think you may have legit need and you probably could see how create your own annotation and add it in lombok.config with  a CUSTOM:fully.qualified.NonNullAnnotation value in lombok.addNullAnnotations parameter *(This feature was added in lombok v1.18.12)*.

@cf : Global config keys in  https://projectlombok.org/features/configuration

GLHF ;)

Comment: So far I must agree that this situation does not have a better solution other than separate all Value annotated classes into specific namespace which is not annotated by NonNullByDefault but rather specify NonNull on each element. And use NonNullByDefault on other packages with business logic. I do not agree with the Lombok developer reasoning as I do not want to generate non null check on package level but rather specify that all my methods and items are not null on whole package level. But I respect his decision as he is the author of this awesome library.